# Can not create new card, when i try to add new record it added into same card doesn't create new card in Ionic 3

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic3

I'm very new in ionic, I'm trying to add records in cards and it added successfully but when i try to add new record it added into same card doesn't create new card with data.I tried with nested component but it won't work. Please help me. Below is my code

.html file

```
   <ion-item>
  <ion-card class="ion-card">
    <ion-card-content
        *ngFor="let bindlcdetail of bindlcdetails" class="ion-card-content">
      {{bindlcdetail}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-item>
```

.ts file

```
  addLocalConveyance(): void {
     this.bindlcdetails.push(`Allotted Type= ${this.allottedtype}`,
                             `vehicle Type= ${this.vehicletype}`,
                             `From Location= ${this.fromlocation}`, 
                             `To Location= ${this.tolocation}`,
                             `From Date= ${this.fromdate}`,
                             `To Date= ${this.todate}`, 
                             `KMs= ${this.kms}`, 
                             `Amount= ${this.amount}`);

   this.fromlocation = '';
   this.tolocation = '';
   this.fromdate = null;
   this.todate = null;
   this.kms = null;
   this.amount = null;
 }
```

Update
      i want output like in img

```
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/doQqb.png
```

Comment: any sketch ? if you given then i will try

Comment: your recent output show here because i done it you which you want ... but your code was right ..

Comment: yes, but my all data shows in singal card i want to show it in diff diff cards

Comment: ok but you showing that in one card .........

Comment: i try to use one card with multiple times with diff data like android

Comment: now check it it work or not..... @Prandya

Comment: If its work then give it right ....@prandya

Comment: voting requires at least 15 reputations and i don't have it

Comment: not required 15 reputation give it correct...... just click on accept icon

Comment: I will give you plus vote. Please give it accept  sign and also plus vote if its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all you need to change in `.html` file.**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-card class="ion-card" *ngFor="let bindlcdetail of bindlcdetails" >
    <ion-card-content class="ion-card-content">
     {{bindlcdetail.allotedType}}
     {{bindlcdetail.vehicleType}}
     {{bindlcdetail.fromLocation}}
     {{bindlcdetail.toLocation}}
     {{bindlcdetail.fromDate}}
     {{bindlcdetail.toDate}}
     {{bindlcdetail.kms}}
     {{bindlcdetail.amount}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-item>
```

**You need to change following in `.ts` file**

```
  addLocalConveyance(): void {


this.bindlcdetails.push(
  {allotedType: `Allotted Type= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    vehicleType: `vehicle Type= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    fromLocation: `From Location= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    toLocation: `To Location= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    fromDate: `From Date= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    toDate: `To Date= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    kms: `KMs= ${this.allottedtype}`,
    amount:  `Amount= ${this.allottedtype}`}
 );

   this.fromlocation = '';
   this.tolocation = '';
   this.fromdate = null;
   this.todate = null;
   this.kms = null;
   this.amount = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there is only one mistake. You put `*ngFor` on a wrong place.

**Just replace it with the below code:**

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let bindlcdetail of bindlcdetails" class="ion-card">
    <ion-card-content class="ion-card-content">
      {{bindlcdetail.allotedType}}
      {{bindlcdetail.vehicleType}}
      {{bindlcdetail.amount}}
      //and other fields
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-item>
```

**And instead of pushing each value separately, push an object containing all the values as shown below.**

```
 this.bindlcdetails.push({allotedType: 'something',
                         vehicleType: 'something',
                         fromLocation: 'location', 
                         toLocation: 'location',
                         fromDate: 'date',
                         toDate: 'date', 
                         kms: 'something', 
                         amount: 10000});
```

Now it will create a new card every time.

Comment: Actually, one card contains all fields from allotted type to amount and then generate second with same fields and so on

Comment: your answer will create every field wise card t i want it in bunch

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. And if it is what you want then please mark it right.